# Updating font size on window resize proportional to window. New values are wrong

Tags: javascript

So here I am trying to do some text resizing which stays proportionate to the window. It works fine, or at least I think it does. If you resize browser and then refresh your page then you will see that it works. The issue however starts to arise with the addition of the window.onresize handler. I do get updated values on resize but, it increments the number to extrem heights. Is there anything wrong with my calculation or should I keep some of my variables outside of the function? I feel the issue is my getFontSize variable. My math might as well be horrible.

I would appreciate some feedback and would like to know what I am doing wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/uu1faumL/

```
window.onresize = flexClass;
var initFlexClass = window.onresize;
initFlexClass();
function flexClass() {
    var wScan = {width: window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth};
    var source = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    var getFontSize = window.getComputedStyle(source, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
    var fontSize = parseFloat(getFontSize);
    var result = Math.ceil((fontSize / 100) * wScan.width);
    source.style.fontSize = result + 'px';
}
```

Comment: So you only want the font to change based on if the width of the document changes? What about height?

Comment: Your issue is most likely that you are not parsing `wScan.width` and it is actually returning a string value as the number and not an actual number. `wScan.width = parseFloat(wScan.width)` would probably fix it.

Comment: @crush right now only the width. It actually works but not in real time. As soon as it computes a new value it gets all crazy

Comment: @ryan that could explain it but I just did a console.log(typeof wScan.width) and it gives me a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is a combination of your math and maintaining state between resizes.

You should probably cache the original size, and compute a new size based on the original size each resize:

```
//Use an IIFE to keep your variables out of global scope.
(function () {
    //Some arbitrary scale factor. Come up with your own, or find a way to calculate it.
    var scaleFactor = 100;

    //Initialize the stuff that doesn't need to be retrieved on every resize event.
    var source = document.getElementById('wrapper'),
        getFontSize = window.getComputedStyle(source, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'),
        fontSize = parseFloat(getFontSize);

    //Here's your resize callback
    var onResize = function () {
        var wScan = { width: window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth };

        //Your math was scaling off both the font size and the width of the document.
        //You should scale the original font-size based on the width of the document every-time.
        var result = Math.ceil(fontSize * wScan.width / scaleFactor);

        source.style.fontSize = result + 'px';
    };

    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener('resize', onResize); //Add your event listener.
    else
        window.attachEvent('onresize', onResize); //IE support.

    onResize(); //Call resize manually the first time.
})();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uu1faumL/3/)

Your original math would mean that the font-size always continues to grow on each resize because you kept fetching the last font-size that you set. That's why your numbers were quickly becoming very large.

Comment: So basically you kept the first three variables outside of my resize function. Everything else will be kept inside. I will get out my calculator. It does work now. I hope I was at least close to achieving what I want!

Comment: `source` isn't going to change between resizes, so it was a waste of resources to keep querying it inside of the resize callback. So I moved it outside. The other two variables are for tracking the font-size. By moving these outside of the callback, they will only be set once as well. It's best to use the original font-size, and scale based on width. You were using the last set font-size, which was causing the new font-size to always grow (unless width would've reached 0 somehow).